# Gluon Mobile: using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, gradle, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I am working on an android app with GluonMobile. For one feature I need a ExoPlayer.
So I included the dependency com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:+ .
It seems that the dependecy is an aar -file and InteliJ could not find any of ExoPlayers classes.
Here my buildscript:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:+'

        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
    maven {
        url uri('libs')
    }
}

mainClassName = '[...].main.Main'
version = '2.0_Alpha'

dependencies {
    compile "com.gluonhq:charm:+"
    compile "com.gluonhq:glisten-afterburner:+"

    compile "com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:+"
    compile "com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:+"
    compile "com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:+"
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:+"
    compileOnly 'lib.idea:annotations:0'

    androidImplementation "org.javafxports:jfxdvk:+"

    androidImplementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:+@aar'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '+'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        plugins 'browser', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        //androidSdk = "${ANDROID_HOME}"
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 22
        minSdkVersion = 16


        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
    }
}

task installApk{
    group = "gluon mobile for android"
    doLast{
        exec {
            workingDir "${ANDROID_HOME}\\platform-tools"
            commandLine "${workingDir}\\adb.exe", "install", "${buildDir}/javafxports/android/YouJavaTubeApp.apk"
        }
    }
}
```

I found already something about explodeAarDependencies(...) but it did not work. So have somebody any ideas how to include (any) aar dependencies to my GluonMobile project.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track about `explodeAarDependencies`, this is the task used by the jfxmobile plugin to unpack .aar dependencies into .jar and other resources.

You can find about the task [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/4cd4ca18e69d8dac2dd0d67ab09e01a1f8faf594/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/JFXMobileConvention.groovy#lines-24).

How to use it:

In your build.gradle file, include the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    androidCompile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.0'
}
```

- Note 1: don't to use `@aar`
- Note 2: the jfxmobile plugin uses some defined configurations like `androidCompile` instead of `androidImplementation`.
- Note 3: I'd rather use the given version, not `+`.

And at the end of the file, add the task:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    explodeAarDependencies(project.configurations.androidCompile)
}
```

And that's it.

Save and apply/sync/reload the build and you should see `exoplayer` and a bunch of transitive dependencies included into the Android compile dependencies, both .aar and .jar files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding dependencies in the wrong gradle file.
There will be 2 gradle files , One for project level and for app level. you need to add your libraries dependencies in app level gradle.

[image: You need to add your dependencies in app level gradle like this]

whereas you might be adding in the project level gradle.

My Gradle file looks like this :

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.0'


}
```

For more details on adding exoplayer pls refer to

[Github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) and 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer